# Using `Block` with Conditions `/;`

Tags: function-construction, scoping

I would like `Block` to run conditionally. I understand how to do one condition, but what about an AND operation?

e.g

```
test[x_, y_] := Block[{}, 
   Print["more than 10"];
   ] /; x > 10 

test[x_, y_] := Block[{}, 
   Print["less than 10"];
   ] /; x <= 10 

test[x_, y_] := Block[{}, 
   Print["x and y more than 10"];
   ] /; x > 10 && y > 10


test[8, 1] (* output: less than 10 *) 
test[20, 1](* output: more than 10 *) 
test[20, 20](* output: more than 10 *)
```

But `test[20, 20]` should output `"x and y more than 10"`. Adding `/; x <= 10 && y<= 10`for the second `test[x_,y_]` block makes no difference.

Comment: If you look at the result of `DownValues[test]`, you'll see the ordering used by *Mathematica* in deciding which definition gets applied first. Have you already tried making the third definition the first one you evaluate?

Comment: This is incredibly helpful and solves the problem. Just an ordering problem. Grr.

Comment: I'm sure this is just a minimal example, but if it is similar to your real application I would consider not using separate down values to control the evaluation.  If you have a series of conditions why not use a `Which` statement?  Just like `test[x_, y_] := Which[ condition1, test1[x,y], condition2, test2[x,y], condition3, test3[x,y], True, fallback[x,y]]`

Comment: As a variation of what @JasonB proposed: `test[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] :=
 Switch[Boole[{x > 10, y > 10}],
   {1, 0}, "more than 10",
   {0, _}, "less than 10",
   {1, 1}, "x and y more than 10"] // Print`

Comment: I'd say that the first def. should be defined correctly thus: `... /; x > 10 && y <= 10`.  Then the logic is clear and correct and ordering does not matter.